# Is it correct use lodash inside a pure function to map an input value?

Tags: redux, ionic2, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Is it okay to use lodash inside a pure function to `_.map` an input value or can I only use the native `Array.map` which is slower?

For example:

```
let shortcuts = _.map(state.shortcuts, (shortcut: any) => {
    switch(shortcut.page){
      case "Transfers":  return tassign(shortcut, { badge: action.payload.transfers }); 
      case "Payments":  return tassign(shortcut, { badge: action.payload.payments }); 
      case "Inbox":  return tassign(shortcut, { badge: action.payload.inbox }); 
      case "ConsolidatedPosition":  return tassign(shortcut, { badge: action.payload.consolidatedPosition }); 
      default: return shortcut; 
    }
  });

  return tassign(state, { shortcuts: shortcuts });
```

Answer (score 1):

Lodash's [`map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) has no state and no side effects, so it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

> A pure function is a function where the return value is only
>   determined by its input values, without observable side effects.

Lodash's map works in a similar to Array.prototype.map() which creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

Generally to keep the function pure, return always a new value and do not perform any other operations outside the scope of that function, like DOM related operations and so on.

Pure functions and redux: http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html